# Reading a Text file with numbers into a vector for working

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

I am a turbo noob at R but I am looking to get my feet wet more with it.  I have a text file with numbers that looks like:

```
1 2 10 15
```

(I can also produce these numbers with a comma and space if needed i.e `1, 2, 10, 15`)

I am attempting to read these numbers as a numerical vector so I can work with them in basic calculations such as graphing, mean, etc.  I attempted to use:

```
data <- scan(file="./logs_formatted/Packets_Delivered_Poll_Formatted.log", what="numeric")
```

However, this produces my numbers as characters like: "1" "2" "10" "15".  This is fine but I cant seem to do any arithmetic with these characters.  I basically just want to read this file and have a vector like:

```
c(1, 2, 10, 15)
```

How do I do this?

I have tried a few functions.

Comment: You need `what = numeric()` i.e. `scan(text = "1 2 10 15", what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)#
[1]  1  2 10 15`

Answer (score 1):

[When using `scan()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/scan), the `what` argument should not be in quotations. It should be `double()`, `character()`, `numeric()`, etc. Since it's not specified correctly, I believe it's defaulting to `double()`.

```
yourvector <- c(1, 2, 10, 15)
write(yourvector, "myfile.txt")
numvector <- scan(file = "myfile.txt", what = numeric(), quote = "")
numvector
#> [1]  1  2 10 15
class(numvector)
#> [1] "numeric"
class(numvector[[1]])
#> [1] "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

We may need `numeric()`

```
data <- scan(file="./logs_formatted/Packets_Delivered_Poll_Formatted.log", what=numeric(),
   quiet = TRUE)
```

-testing

```
scan(text = "1 2 10 15", what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)
# [1]  1  2 10 15
```